# filter dataframe by rule from rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I got a xlsx file, data distributed with some rule. I need collect data base on the rule. e.g. valid data begin row is "y3", data row is the cell below that row.

In below sample,

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [
    ["A","y3","y2","y3","y4"],
    ["B",0,2,3,3],
    ["C","y3","y4","y5","y6"],
    ["D",2,4,5,0],
    ["E","y1","y2","y3","y4"],
    ["F",0,2,4,3],
    ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5'])
print(df1)
```

expected output:

```
:   C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
: 0  A  y3  y2  y3  y4
: 1  B   0   2   3   3
: 2  C  y3  y4  y5  y6
: 3  D   2   4   5   0
: 4  E  y1  y2  y3  y4
: 5  F   0   2   4   3

:    v1  y3  
: 0  B  0 
: 0  B  3 
: 1  D  2
: 1  F  4
```

Since 3 and 4 followed by y3 in column C4 and 0,2 followed by y3 in column C2 as well.

Comment: Can you have more than one y3 per row?

Comment: yes, exactly, let me mentioned it.

Comment: I meant per **row**, here you added another y3 in the same **column** (which is not an issue) ;)

Comment: good findings, I add both row and col samples

Comment: OK, then my current answer should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
tmp = df1.set_index('C1', append=True)

out = (tmp[tmp.shift().eq('y3')]
       .stack().droplevel(-1)
       .rename_axis([None, 'v1'])
       .reset_index(level=1, name='v3')
      )
```

Output:

```
  v1 v3
1  B  0
1  B  3
3  D  2
5  F  4
```

Comment: Great, if the following data is 2 rows, should I change the drop leve to 2?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but no the `droplevel` is to remove the column names after stacking

Comment: I mean  if the expected value row is the second row followed by y3.

Comment: Please try my solution and let me know if this works. If you have a different use case, please update the question with all the details.

Comment: Thanks, current answer is perfect. will submit new one for others!